# full screen image random when browser refreshed Javascript

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

Hey there i've been trying to make an image full screen in the browser without any whitespace and also have a random image everytime you refresh the browser, I know there has to be a way to do that maybe with an image array? Can anyone help i have no idea how to even start.
       So far this is what i came up with:

```
    var images=new Array();
    images[0]="images/image1.jpg";
    images[1]="images/image2.jpg";
    images[2]="images/image3.jpg";
    images[3]="images/image4.jpg";
```

Please help me! i would really love it!

Comment: If you haven't already, you will need some css to make the image full screen.